# C# WebRequest POST returns 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

I want to submit xml via postbody to a web service, but am getting a 500 Error from the `GetResponse()` method.

Here is my snippet:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Pass", "Domain");

byte[] body= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myXML);
request.ContentLength = body.Length;

request.GetRequestStream().Write(body, 0, body.Length);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); //500 response
```

Does anyone know why the server is responding with this error? Am I providing all the needed headers? I have confirmed that the service works through a REST Client Console, but can't seem to `POST` to it via code.

Comment: how can you say that it is the current context? you should have the  http current context request

Comment: Who knows. Maybe your xml is not the one your server expects

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead of `request.ContentType = "application/xml"` for it to correctly `POST` the xml data in the request. If anyone out there has a the technical explanation as to why `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` worked instead of `application/xml`, I would love to hear it.